# Case insensitive i18n string search in grails

Tags: java, grails, internationalization

If I have in a `message.properties` file the following line

```
myClass.label= My Classs
```

How can I make a case insensitive search for it? For example using `message(code:"MyClass.label")` (with an uppercase 'M').

Also, is there a reason why grails's scaffolding searches for classes label with the first character lowercase instead of uppercase?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Property files, and thus resource bundles such as messages.properties are case sensitive by specification. Secondly, the reason for the lower case first letter of a class name is to meet bean naming standards.

If you really want to make an insensitive search for message codes you will need to define and implement your own messageSource bean. It would be worth reading how [this is done](http://docs.spring.io/spring/docs/2.5.x/reference/beans.html#context-functionality-messagesource) in Spring.